# How can I fix this issue with Windows path on Qt and Qurl?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and I wrote a script to download some videos and then save them into a specific directory. First I write the paths from a Linux machine, but now I'm using a pc with Windows 10 and when I open the video anything appears. Anybody knows what's the problem? I can download the videos, but it's like the path doesn't exist or something like that. There's no errors on the log.

```
self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(videoPath)))
```

I'm using this line to put the video into the mediaPlayer and everything works fine on my Linux, but when I turn to Windows nothing appears. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: yes, sorry for my english

Comment: @user16163887 1) What is the format of the resource: .mp4, .mp3, etc? 2) Have you installed the codecs like k-lite codecs?

Comment: What's the value of `os.path.isfile(videoPath)`?

Comment: the format is .mp4 and the value is a windows path like c:\ ... \ ... .mp4; I don't remember if I installed any codec, I'm gonna check that, but in my linux works fine and the path is like / ... / ... .mp4

Comment: It was the codecs, thank you so much